# Fixing error: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so'

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, makefile

I have recently upgraded my OS (to PopOS! 22.04) and now a bunch of builds in my cmake workflow aren't compiling, halting at this particular error at the linking stage:

> *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so'

This file now no longer exists. There is however a `libdl.so.2`.

Running `apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so` gives no output.

How can I get my builds working again?

EDIT:

The solution turned out to be due to manually built dependencies/packages that obviously weren't updated during the upgrade. I had to go and rebuild them, and then the error disappeared. Note, when rebuilding them (also with CMake) it required a full deletion of the build directory, not just running CMake again.

Comment: A silly question, but did you re-run CMake again after updating?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. I did, and not a silly question! But have figured it out now - I had some manual dependencies which themselves needed to be rebuilt after the upgrade. FYI, or to anyone reading, running CMake on these was not enough to solve it - in the full CMake process I needed to delete the build directory and start entirely from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jammy's GNU C Libarry version is 2.35. The `dl` library is now part of the C standard library. The [release notes](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-August/129718.html), tells that, starting from version 2.34,

> all functionality formerly
> implemented in the libraries `libpthread`, `libdl`, `libutil`, `libanl` has
> been integrated into `libc`.  New applications do not need to link with
> `-lpthread`, `-ldl`, `-lutil`, `-lanl` anymore.  For backwards compatibility,
> empty static archives `libpthread.a`, `libdl.a`, `libutil.a`, `libanl.a` are
> provided, so that the linker options keep working.  Applications which
> have been linked against `glibc` 2.33 or earlier continue to load the
> corresponding shared objects (which are now empty).

This means that you have to remove the explicit `libdl.so` from the linker dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. Some manually built packages were trying to link to `libdl.so`, so I need to fully rebuild/reinstall them, ad then start the CMake process from scratch on my project - that worked.